Difference of two half-wave signals for BJT rectifier
I am playing around with this circuit that uses two PNP's and two NPN's to make sort of a crappy full wave rectifier. The intent is to invert one of the signals and add the two (aka subtraction) and the reduce ripple using a capacitor.
The final goal is to use this DC that is proportional to the audio input as a control signal for a JFET based audio compressor.
I however cannot seem to figure out a good way to take the difference of both signals without ruining input signal integrity. I have tried Op-Amps and differential bjt pairs but I am struggling on how to set the topologies op. Can someone please offer some suggestions?
I have now included the full circuit and plotted both the input and the ouputs of the AC to DC circuit.

*edit: I figured it out using a TL071 Op-Amp and by improving the output impedance of the transitor stages. The latest values for R17, R18, R19, R22, R23, R24 and R25 respectively are:
13k, 7k, 2k, 7k, 4k, 4.7k, 3k. To account for mismatch in performance between the NPN and the PNP. The difference of the outputs is taken by the opamp using the suggested design but lowering the feedback resistor to 5k because that gives enough gain to meet my requirements.

A rectifier makes a DC from AC. But what I see is one positive signal and one negative, thus still AC. Try to explain/draft what the input is and how the output should look like.

Node numbers on plots mean nothing to the reader.

I added some more context to the prompt, thanks for the quick response

Are Q3 and Q4 upside down?

An opamp with bipolar supplies set up as a differential amplifier will do this no problem. you can even skip the coupling capacitor.

photo source: this SE post Can't balance differential amplifier circuit
It will have some error due to tolerance in resistors, you can buy a trimmed difference amplifier or an instrumentation amplifier if this is an issue for you.
Basically, take the pasted circuit with 100k resistors, use an ideal or real opamp model in your sim, give it +/-18V supplies, and voila.
I'm not sure what your BJT circuit output impedance is, so maybe you will have to increase the resistor values, but your sim should tell you this.
begs the question, however: what are you trying to accomplish?

Thanks for the suggestion, however the output voltage blows up to infinity when I try that...
